# Solve the 'Eigenvalue' problem efficiently

Tags: numerics, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

Usually, an eigenvalue of a matrix A is defined as |A-b*I|=0, where I is the identity matrix and |..| is for the determinant.

Now my question becomes a little different, let's say A is a function of b. Therefore, if I still want to calculate the eigenvalue of A, I cannot directly use something like Eigensystem[A]. The meaning of such a problem lies in the Green's function in quantum field theory. Sometimes the Hamiltonian includes a self-energy term which is dependent on omega(energy).

To avoid raising XY problem, I just post some of my previous effort in the last, which may or may not be helpful. I have tried to go back to the definition of eigenvalue, namely |A(b)-b*I|=0. And use FindRoot, but very strangely, the returned answer is always 0. I guess it's due to the numeric error. Becuase there're many high order polynomials in the determinant. Later, I find a more severe problem that it is even not possible to solve the eigenvalues of a normal matrix using the definition of eigenvalue and finding roots of it unless putting every number in fraction and using symbolic calculation. Here is a simple example to reproduce the situation:

```
A = Partition[Range[64], 8]
eiv = Eigenvalues[A]
```

The result is

```
{2 (65 + Sqrt[4897]), 2 (65 - Sqrt[4897]), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

If I try to substitute the root back to determinant:

```
(Det[A - b*IdentityMatrix[8]] /. b -> # &) /@ eiv // N
```

It will not return 0 for all eigenvalues:

```
{4096., 5.06639*10^-7, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}
```

Instead, if I use symbolic way,

```
(Det[A - b*IdentityMatrix[8]] /. b -> # &) /@ eiv // Simplify
```

it works

```
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

But the actual problem will be a very large sparse matrix around 4000 by 4000, which is not feasible to do a symbolic calculation. While the numeric calculate has such a big error, which doesn't work either.

Thanks for your time! Any comment will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you use `N[#, {$MachinePrecision, 100}] &` instead of `N`?

Comment: If I understand your word correctly, I used N[Eigenvalue[A],{$MachinePrecision, 100}]. It gives me some very weird output: {0.*10^4, 0.*10^-6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}. And the first element is red framed, saying no significant digits are available to display.

Comment: In don't get it, `(Det[A - #*IdentityMatrix[8]] &) /@ eiv // N` returns precisely `{0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}`...